# Returning additional parameters from JSON

Tags: c#, html, json

From the controller I want to return a `JSON` response which will also include a `persons name` returned from it.

At the moment, the JSON returns if the operation was success or not and `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`.

C# code from controller:

```
 return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Note: From the controller, I want to include an extra parameter that returns the logged-in users name. How can I code this ?

Front End:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Person/Logged",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,

    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert("person logged in is ? ");
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try returning

```
return Json(new {name="myname"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Person/Logged",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,

    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert("person logged in is ? "+ data.name);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Json("{'success': true, 'name': 'bob chod'}", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```